# The volume levels when using different channels for microphones are clearly too low. Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: alsa, microphone

The volume levels when using different channels for microphones are clearly too low.
The error occurs with the internal microphone, the headset microphone as well as the USB microphone.
Approx. 30dB were detected with „Audacity“.
My hardware: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=f4c6260289
Suspect the core Kubuntu 22.04?